# In django-allauth, how do I add the OpenId social app?

Tags: django, openid, django-allauth

Just starting to learn django, and I wanted to incorporate the allauth app.
Been trying to figure this out all day and haven't found the answer in other questions.
Anytime I try to add one of the social logins, I can't even get a login screen and django complains:

```
get_login_url() keywords must be strings
```

when it tries to render the provider list.  (I copied over base, index, and profile from the example that came with allauth)

I've read that before I use one of the logins, I need to add the social app in the admin interface.  So in the admin interface, I want to try one of the simpler ones, so i chose OpenId.  Since I don't have a facebook app id or anything yet, I figured with OpenId, I wouldn't need that.

I'm getting hung up on what to use for the Key and Secret to register the social app.  I'm new to this stuff, but I thought that was more for OAuth.  But if I don't include it, it flags the fields as red and demands them.  Where do I find/generate a Key/Secret?

Also, to use OpenId, am I supposed to specify a site like Google or Yahoo, or is there just an "OpenId" site?

I'm still using manage.py runserver, if that makes any difference.  But I thought I would still be able to get the page to "render."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Python are you running? If you are using an old 2.6 version, then you may be running into the issue described here:

http://cuu508.wordpress.com/2011/01/27/keywords-must-be-strings/

Please let me know if that pinpoints your problem. If so, I'll check if I can make `allauth` play nice with your version...

Update: haven't had the time to test this myself yet, could you give this change a try?:

```
--- a/allauth/socialaccount/templatetags/socialaccount.py
+++ b/allauth/socialaccount/templatetags/socialaccount.py
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@ class ProviderLoginURLNode(template.Node):
     def render(self, context):
         provider_id = self.provider_id_var.resolve(context)
         provider = providers.registry.by_id(provider_id)
-        query = dict([(name, var.resolve(context)) for name, var
+        query = dict([(str(name), var.resolve(context)) for name, var
                       in self.params.iteritems()])
         request = context['request']
         if not query.has_key('next'):
```

Comment: python --version
Python 2.6.1
(on Snow Leopard - so yeah, that could be it.)

Interesting... at first I thought it was a runserver vs real deployment thing so I put it up on a less convenient linux site and it started working.  But now i realize my local python is 2.6.1 and the remote site is 2.6.6

I couldn't tell from the link - is there a workaround, like is there a file I need to edit?

Thank you!

Comment: happening in line 9 of allauth/templates/socialaccount/snippets/provider_list.html
 href="{% provider_login_url provider.id openid=brand.openid_url %}"
which looks like it traces back to line 53 of /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django_allauth-0.7.1-py2.6.egg/allauth/account/views.py     return render_to_response(template_name, RequestContext(request, ctx))

Comment: That change looks like it worked.  I started up manage.py runserver again locally (uses the older python), and with the above fix, I now get the login page with no type errors.  So... looks good!  Thanks!